# In swift, how can I check if any of the elements within an array exist as keys within a dictionary, then return the value of those keys?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm very new to programming. In Swift I want to do something like this:

```
var animalArray = ["dog", "cow", "duck"]
var animalDictionary = ["frog": "ribbit", "dog": "woof", "cat": "meow"]
if /*element in animalArray exists as a key within animalDictionary*/ {
    print(value)
}
```

In this instance, "dog" does exist as a key, and I want the console to print out "woof"

Also, if more than one of the elements in the array do exist as keys within the dictionary, how can I print out both, or only print one of them?

Comment: There are two tasks here: learning whether a key is in the dictionary and getting its value, and looping through the potential keys in the array. Which is giving you difficulty?

Comment: May I recommend the [Swift book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/), it's an excellent reference book and introduction to Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write your code for you, but I'll point out that, as you learn how to do this sort of thing, you need to separate this into two tasks, one containing the other:

```
var animalArray = ["dog", "cow", "duck"]
var animalDictionary = ["frog": "ribbit", "dog": "woof", "cat": "meow"]
for /* each element in animal array */ {
    if /* it exists as a key within animalDictionary*/ {
        print(value)
    }
}
```

So you need to learn how to loop (`for`) as well as how to query a dictionary.